# Two modules require each other - corona

Tags: module, lua, coronasdk, require

I have : "play.lua" and "menu.lua" and and it works perfect. in "menu.lua": local play = require('play').
I made a button that takes you back to menu, so i wrote in "play.lua": local menu = require('menu') and that shows me error. and when I require just 'menu' in play.lua every thing is ok?
so what is the problem?
I can't two modules to require each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can's have two modules that require each other; if you try that you are likely to get `loop or previous error loading module 'X'` error. The situation is the same as you get with recursive functions when `a` calls `b`, which calls `a`: the recursion requires some stopping criteria, otherwise it will continue indefinitely. Lua authors implemented a check to detect this situation for `require` and generate the error you see.

You need to restructure your code to avoid this. You can, for example, extract shared code from `play` into `core` and instead of requiring `play` from `menu`, require `core` from both of them, which will eliminate the issue.